# How to get the locations list with Google My Business API

Tags: javascript, c#, google-my-business-api

I am trying to get the locations list of a user with Google My Business Javascript API (https://developers.google.com/my-business/quickstarts/javascript).  A user logs in successfully with his google credentials and oauth token is generated.  But When I am trying to get the locations--->

```
        var apiKey = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxx';
        var clientId = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';
        var gmb_api_version = 'https://mybusiness.googleapis.com/v4';

        let user = gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().currentUser.get();
        let oauthToken = user.getAuthResponse().access_token;
        let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        let req = gmb_api_version + '/' + 'accounts/' + user.getId() + '/locations';

        xhr.responseType = 'json';
        xhr.open('GET', req);
        xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + oauthToken);
        xhr.send();
```

I am getting null in xhr.response object.

Comment: did you got any error?

Answer (score 0):

It is somehow late to answer but in case somebody needs:
If you do not have the error then probably, just the account has no locations. first check the google response in [https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/], trying to see if you have the different response.